# Admin grids are stuck on loading until refresh the page in magneto 2.4.5-p2

Tags: magento, magento2

After login in Magento admin grids are stuck on loading. It's continue loading until we not refresh the page while the grids are stuck on loading we are not even able to open any other tabs from admin for example : if I open sale -> order grid [ its stuck on loading ] & other tabs are not working too Sometimes its happen after login in Magento admin and tabs are not working - sales - catalogs etc. all the not working or not clickable .

We have done the following till now to solve this issue but the issue is fixed : We check all the log files and there are no errors . We try removing ui_bookmark table its not work for us too we try debug the error but we find nothing we are on production mode and we change the mode into developer to find the issue in frontend or in log but again we got nothing in log files or no error in frontend. Could anyone please suggest the solution to fix this issue so that we can proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing this all time from Magento 2.4.5 and above, I suspect this is a issue with browser cache, you can refresh or temporally disable the cache [here](https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache/).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks this probably related to a bug that is caused by Adobe and their tracking tool and we fix this permanently by using this following ways :

bin/magento config:set admin/usage/enabled 0;
bin/magento cache:clean;

More info can be found here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37618#issuecomment-1592991014

Hope it will help you

Comment: Generally answer is good, but better answer will not only include link but also example related to question